# Choosing data from a list of tuples in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I have a list of tuples of tuples of type `:: [((a, b), (a, b), (a, b))]`, in Haskell.

For some context, the 3 points `(a, b)` represent a (time, value) pair on a U shaped curve with the first point, at the initial time t1 having a maximum value on the curve x1, the third point with a greater time t3=t1+dt and a value x3

I would like find the range for the widest U in the list `[((t1, x1), (t2, x2), (t3, x3))]` by taking the tuple with the maximum `t3 - t1`, and then returning the value `x2 - x1`.

The only way I can think to do it is to first map each tuple in the list to `t3 - t1`, find its index, then calculate x2 - x1 for that index in the original list. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
findMaxTime :: [((a, b), (a, b), (a, b))] -> Int
findMaxTime list = elemIndex (==min) $ map (\(x, y, z) -> fst z - fst x)
                       where min = minimum $ map (\(x, y, z) -> fst z - fst x)

findMaxVal :: [((a, b), (a, b), (a, b))] -> b
findMaxVal list = list !! findMaxTime list
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, Ash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `maximumBy` with `comparing`:

```
module Main where

import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.List (maximumBy)

findMaxVal :: (Num a, Ord a, Num b, Ord b) => [((a, b), (a, b), (a, b))] -> b
findMaxVal = xWidth . maximumBy (comparing tWidth)
  where
    xWidth ((_, x1), (_, x2), _) = x2 - x1
    tWidth ((t1, _), _, (t3, _)) = t3 - t1
```

Comment: I just used this solution myself about 30 minutes ago.

Comment: http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/src/Data-List.html#maximumBy and http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/src/Data-List.html#foldl1 if you care. Easy enough to plunk in a foldl' and write your own maximumBy'